# How does the Huntress's Long Range skill work?

Tags: dungeon-defenders-2

The [Long Range](http://dungeondefenders2.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Huntress#Specs) spec for the Huntress reads:

> Basic Attacks deal more damage the longer they travel, up to +% more

I'm confused on how this works.  Is there some kind of arbitrary distance that will give the full % boost and everything else is a percentage of that max?  Is there a set distance that increases for each point you put in and anything beyond it is capped at that max?  How, specifically, does this Long Range spec work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's an arbitrary distance max that gives the full boost, and any distance shorter than that is a percentage of that max. You can test this on tavern dummies by shooting a fair distance away, then moving forward or back a small distance. The damage numbers will change by a tiny amount.